# What is a correct way to solve undefined reference to undefined reference to `LLVMInitializeAArch64TargetInfo'

Tags: cmake, llvm

In Clion when i build llvm project I got following message:

```
CMakeFiles/codegen_llvm.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos()':
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/Config/Targets.def:26: undefined reference to `LLVMInitializeAArch64TargetInfo'
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/Config/Targets.def:27: undefined reference to `LLVMInitializeAMDGPUTargetInfo'
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/Config/Targets.def:28: undefined reference to `LLVMInitializeARMTargetInfo'
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/Config/Targets.def:29: undefined reference to `LLVMInitializeBPFTargetInfo'
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/Config/Targets.def:30: undefined reference to `LLVMInitializeHexagonTargetInfo'
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/Config/Targets.def:31: undefined reference to `LLVMInitializeLanaiTargetInfo'
```

And My CmakeLists is here:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(codegen_llvm)
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

message(STATUS "Found ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")

include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(codegen_llvm main.cpp)

llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs support core irreader executionEngine)
target_link_libraries(codegen_llvm  ${llvm_libs})
...
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

cmake solution

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(project_name )

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)

link_libraries()
execute_process(COMMAND llvm-config --libs OUTPUT_VARIABLE LIBS)
execute_process(COMMAND llvm-config --system-libs OUTPUT_VARIABLE SYS_LIBS)
execute_process(COMMAND llvm-config --ldflags OUTPUT_VARIABLE LDF)
#message(STATUS "Found LLVM" ${LIBS})

string(STRIP ${LIBS} LIBS)
string(STRIP ${SYS_LIBS} SYS_LIBS)
string(STRIP ${LDF} LDF)

link_libraries(${LIBS} ${SYS_LIBS} ${LDF})

execute_process(COMMAND llvm-config --cxxflags OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS)
string(STRIP ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS)

add_executable(project_name   toy.cpp)
```

one liner

```
clang++ -g toy.cpp $(llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs) -O3 -o toy
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still do not have a solution for this error, try to add `${LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD}` to your link libraries.

I am using CLion too, and I solved this by changing:

`llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs support core irreader codegen mc mcparser option)`

to:

`llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs ${LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD} support core irreader codegen mc mcparser option)`

Answer (score 0):

In your last but one line `config` is not an llvm component, so you'd want to remove it. To see the list of official components, use the `llvm-config --components` command.

Comment: But when i delete config it has bug like this:
```
undefined reference to `LLVMInitializeAArch64TargetInfo'
```

Comment: Try linking with all linkable llvm libraries. Delete or comment the last but one line and replace the last line with `target_link_libraries(codegen_llvm  ${llvm-config --libs})`

Comment: And maybe your target_link_libraries Clion will show error.

Comment: @droptop, your code causes: `when parsing string` `${llvm-config` `syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting }`